# Calculating duration by subtracting two datetime columns in string format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Spark Dataframe in that consists of a series of dates:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
import pandas as pd

rdd = sc.parallelizesc.parallelize([('X01','2014-02-13T12:36:14.899','2014-02-13T12:31:56.876','sip:4534454450'),
                                    ('X02','2014-02-13T12:35:37.405','2014-02-13T12:32:13.321','sip:6413445440'),
                                    ('X03','2014-02-13T12:36:03.825','2014-02-13T12:32:15.229','sip:4534437492'),
                                    ('XO4','2014-02-13T12:37:05.460','2014-02-13T12:32:36.881','sip:6474454453'),
                                    ('XO5','2014-02-13T12:36:52.721','2014-02-13T12:33:30.323','sip:8874458555')])
schema = StructType([StructField('ID', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('EndDateTime', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('StartDateTime', StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

What I want to do is find `duration` by subtracting `EndDateTime` and `StartDateTime`. I figured I'd try and do this using a function:

```
# Function to calculate time delta
def time_delta(y,x): 
    end = pd.to_datetime(y)
    start = pd.to_datetime(x)
    delta = (end-start)
    return delta

# create new RDD and add new column 'Duration' by applying time_delta function
df2 = df.withColumn('Duration', time_delta(df.EndDateTime, df.StartDateTime))
```

However this just gives me:

```
>>> df2.show()
ID  EndDateTime          StartDateTime        ANI            Duration
X01 2014-02-13T12:36:... 2014-02-13T12:31:... sip:4534454450 null    
X02 2014-02-13T12:35:... 2014-02-13T12:32:... sip:6413445440 null    
X03 2014-02-13T12:36:... 2014-02-13T12:32:... sip:4534437492 null    
XO4 2014-02-13T12:37:... 2014-02-13T12:32:... sip:6474454453 null    
XO5 2014-02-13T12:36:... 2014-02-13T12:33:... sip:8874458555 null
```

I'm not sure if my approach is correct or not. If not, I'd gladly accept another suggested way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the REPL?

Comment: @dskrvk I don't have much experience debugging since I'm not a developer. However, I suspect the issue is in how Spark hands off data to functions. For example, time_delta() works in pure Python. For some reason, certain Python/Pandas functions just don't play nice. E.g. import re def extract_ani(x): extract = x.str.extract(r'(\d{10})') return extract Dates = Dates.withColumn('Cell', extract_ani(Dates.ANI)) also errors out with Spark DataFrames, but works when I convert the dataframe to an RDD and use the function as part of a `sc.map`

Comment: In Scala I would use TimestampType instead of StringType to hold the dates, and then create a UDF to calculate the difference between the two columns. I don't see anywhere that you declare time_delta to be user defined function, but that's a required step in Scala to make it do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah take a look at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions under pyspark.sql.functions.udf. You need to create time_delta as a UDF

Comment: @David Griffin you were right :) I initially disregarded registering UDF's as I believed you had to register UDFs only of you wanted to use the `select` expression

Comment: Incidentally, had you been using a more strongly typed language like Scala you would have gotten a complaint about trying to pass Columns into a function that is expecting String arguments.

Comment: Yes, that was the other issue..Initially, I was trying to use `pd.to_datetime()` but that is a pandas function that expects columns.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As of Spark 1.5 you can use [unix_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
timeDiff = (F.unix_timestamp('EndDateTime', format=timeFmt)
            - F.unix_timestamp('StartDateTime', format=timeFmt))
df = df.withColumn("Duration", timeDiff)
```

Note the Java style time format.

```
>>> df.show()
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
| ID|         EndDateTime|       StartDateTime|Duration|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|X01|2014-02-13T12:36:...|2014-02-13T12:31:...|     258|
|X02|2014-02-13T12:35:...|2014-02-13T12:32:...|     204|
|X03|2014-02-13T12:36:...|2014-02-13T12:32:...|     228|
|XO4|2014-02-13T12:37:...|2014-02-13T12:32:...|     269|
|XO5|2014-02-13T12:36:...|2014-02-13T12:33:...|     202|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: You can divide by 3600.0 to convert to hours `df.withColumn("Duration_hours", df.Duration / 3600.0)`

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to David Griffin. Here's how to do this for future reference.

```python
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

# Build sample data
rdd = sc.parallelize([('X01','2014-02-13T12:36:14.899','2014-02-13T12:31:56.876'),
                      ('X02','2014-02-13T12:35:37.405','2014-02-13T12:32:13.321'),
                      ('X03','2014-02-13T12:36:03.825','2014-02-13T12:32:15.229'),
                      ('XO4','2014-02-13T12:37:05.460','2014-02-13T12:32:36.881'),
                      ('XO5','2014-02-13T12:36:52.721','2014-02-13T12:33:30.323')])
schema = StructType([StructField('ID', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('EndDateTime', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('StartDateTime', StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# define timedelta function (obtain duration in seconds)
def time_delta(y,x): 
    from datetime import datetime
    end = datetime.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    start = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    delta = (end-start).total_seconds()
    return delta

# register as a UDF 
f = udf(time_delta, IntegerType())

# Apply function
df2 = df.withColumn('Duration', f(df.EndDateTime, df.StartDateTime))
```

Applying `time_delta()` will give you duration in seconds:

```
>>> df2.show()
ID  EndDateTime          StartDateTime        Duration
X01 2014-02-13T12:36:... 2014-02-13T12:31:... 258     
X02 2014-02-13T12:35:... 2014-02-13T12:32:... 204     
X03 2014-02-13T12:36:... 2014-02-13T12:32:... 228     
XO4 2014-02-13T12:37:... 2014-02-13T12:32:... 268     
XO5 2014-02-13T12:36:... 2014-02-13T12:33:... 202
```

Comment: Please use (end-start).total_seconds() . Otherwise you get nasty surprises like this: 
time_delta('2014-02-13T12:36:14.000', '2014-02-13T12:36:15.900') returns 86398 instead of -1.9

Comment: This code doesnt work any more. The duration comes out as null. Using zeppelin, spark 1.6

Answer (score 14):

```
datediff(Column end, Column start)
```

Returns the number of days from start to end.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in spark-sql by converting the string date to timestamp and then getting the difference.

1: Convert to timestamp:

```
CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MY_COL_NAME,'dd-MMM-yy') as TIMESTAMP)
```

2: Get the difference between dates using `datediff` function.

This will be combined in a nested function like:

```
spark.sql("select COL_1, COL_2, datediff( CAST( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( COL_1,'dd-MMM-yy') as TIMESTAMP), CAST( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( COL_2,'dd-MMM-yy') as TIMESTAMP) ) as LAG_in_days from MyTable")
```

Below is the result:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+
|    COL_1|    COL_2|LAG_in_days|
+---------+---------+-----------+
|24-JAN-17|16-JAN-17|          8|
|19-JAN-05|18-JAN-05|          1|
|23-MAY-06|23-MAY-06|          0|
|18-AUG-06|17-AUG-06|          1|
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Reference: https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/2458071/Date+Functions+and+Properties+Spark+SQL

Answer (score 1):

Use DoubleType instead of IntegerType

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


# Build sample data
rdd = sc.parallelize([('X01','2014-02-13T12:36:14.899','2014-02-13T12:31:56.876'),
                      ('X02','2014-02-13T12:35:37.405','2014-02-13T12:32:13.321'),
                      ('X03','2014-02-13T12:36:03.825','2014-02-13T12:32:15.229'),
                      ('XO4','2014-02-13T12:37:05.460','2014-02-13T12:32:36.881'),
                      ('XO5','2014-02-13T12:36:52.721','2014-02-13T12:33:30.323')])
schema = StructType([StructField('ID', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('EndDateTime', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('StartDateTime', StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# define timedelta function (obtain duration in seconds)
def time_delta(y,x): 
    from datetime import datetime
    end = datetime.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    start = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    delta = (end-start).total_seconds()
    return delta

# register as a UDF 
f = udf(time_delta, DoubleType())

# Apply function
df2 = df.withColumn('Duration', f(df.EndDateTime, df.StartDateTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version for spark 2.x derived from jason's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30315921/2851870)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()

rdd = sc.parallelize([('X01','2014-02-13T12:36:14.899','2014-02-13T12:31:56.876'),
                      ('X02','2014-02-13T12:35:37.405','2014-02-13T12:32:13.321'),
                      ('X03','2014-02-13T12:36:03.825','2014-02-13T12:32:15.229'),
                      ('XO4','2014-02-13T12:37:05.460','2014-02-13T12:32:36.881'),
                      ('XO5','2014-02-13T12:36:52.721','2014-02-13T12:33:30.323')])
schema = StructType([StructField('ID', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('EndDateTime', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('StartDateTime', StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# register as a UDF 
from datetime import datetime
sqlContext.registerFunction("time_delta", lambda y,x:(datetime.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')-datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')).total_seconds())

df.createOrReplaceTempView("Test_table")

spark.sql("SELECT ID,EndDateTime,StartDateTime,time_delta(EndDateTime,StartDateTime) as time_delta FROM Test_table").show()

sc.stop()
```