# Date Arithmetic with Multiple Columns in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do some medium-complicated date arithmetic using multiple columns in a PySpark data frame. Basically, I have a column called `number` that represents the number of weeks after the `created_at` timestamp I need to filter on. In PostgreSQL you can multiply an [interval based on the value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266758/dynamic-column-based-interval), but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in PySpark using either the SQL API or the Python API. Any help here would be much appreciated!

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
start_date = datetime.date(2020,1,1)

my_df = sc.parallelize([
        Row(id=1, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), number=1,  metric=10),
        Row(id=1, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), number=2,  metric=10),
        Row(id=1, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), number=3,  metric=10),
        Row(id=2, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15), number=1,  metric=20),
        Row(id=2, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15), number=2,  metric=20),
        Row(id=3, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1), number=7,  metric=30),
        Row(id=3, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1), number=8,  metric=30),
        Row(id=3, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1), number=9,  metric=30),
        Row(id=3, created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1), number=10, metric=30),
    ]).toDF()


# This doesn't work!
new_df = my_df.where("created_at + interval 7 days * number > '" + start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +"'")
# Neither does this!
new_df = my_df.filter(my_df.created_at + datetime.timedelta(days=my_df.number * 7)).date() > start_date.date()
```

There is a possible [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283415/calculating-duration-by-subtracting-two-datetime-columns-in-string-format) that would require converting the date to a string, using the `datetime` library in python to convert the string to a `datetime` object, then performing the operation, but that seems crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I figured out a way forward using the `expr` and the built-in `date_add` functions.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, date_add
new_df = my_df.withColumn('test', expr('date_add(created_at, number*7)'))
filtered = new_df.filter(new_df.test > start_date)
filtered.show()
```

Would love some insight into how/why this works in a general way, though, if someone else wants to add on!